# Why is ReadAsStringAsync async?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So, in the following snippet, why is ReadAsStringAsync an async method?

```
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Originally I expected SendAsync to send the request and load the response stream into memory at which point reading that stream would be in-process CPU work (and not really async).

Going down the source code rabbit hole, I arrived at this:

```
 int count = await _stream.ReadAsync(destination, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0aa654834405dcec4aaa9bd416b2b31ab8d3503e/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Managed/HttpConnection.cs#L967

This makes me think that maybe the connection is open until the response stream is actually read from some source outside of the process? I fully expect that I am missing some fundamentals regarding how streams from Http Connections work.

Comment: SendAsync returns as soon as the *headers* are received. You still have to read the *content* which can be many KBs or MBs in size.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`SendAsync()` waits for the request to finish and the response to *start* arriving.

It doesn't buffer the entire response; this allows you to stream large responses without ever holding the entire response in memory.

Comment: Maybe a link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/call-asynchronous-apis-in-csharp-or-visual-basic would be better. Responsiveness is the design principle here to always prefer async methods.

Comment: @LexLi how is this link relevant to either question or answer?

Comment: @Evk only the first few paragraphs are related, like "Asynchronous APIs keep your app from waiting for large operations to complete before continuing execution. For example, an app that downloads info from the Internet might spend several seconds waiting for the info to arrive. If you use a synchronous method to retrieve the info, the app is blocked until the method returns. The app won't respond to user interaction and because it seems non-responsive, the user might become frustrated."

Comment: thanks! guess I shouldv'e checked the docs first: https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.7

> 
"This operation will not block. Depending on the value of the completionOption parameter, the returned Task<TResult> object will complete as soon as a response is available or the entire response including content is read."

Comment: it looks like the default completion option is ResponseContentRead 
meaning that is not true by default https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b7b34392afa430caf03d197789a493fd122db445/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L20